# Parse json output directly from a subprocess output

Tags: python, json, subprocess

I can't figure out how parse json output directly from a subprocess output.

**code snippet**

```
cmd = ['./mmdbinspect', '--db', '/usr/local/var/GeoIP/GeoLite2-City.mmdb', ip]
        # result returns json
        result = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        result = json.loads(result)
        # parse & print
        print(result[0]['Lookup'])
        print(result[0]['Records'][0]['Record']['country']['iso_code'])
        print(result[0]['Records'][0]['Record']['country']['names']['en'])
```

If I write result to file, then perform json.load it works as expected but I would like to combine and skip that step.

**Traceback error**

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not CompletedProcess
```

Comment: if ``result`` is a JSON string, you want to use ``json.loads`` (notice the "s" at the end) instead of ``json.load``.

Comment: Did you get an error with this code? If so, post the traceback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the docs *The returned instance will have attributes args, returncode, stdout and stderr*. To use it, load the json string from stdout.

```
result = json.loads(result.stdout)
```

Comment: I had tried json.load(result.stdout) but not json.loads(result.stdout). Thank you so much!

Comment: It's important that must pass stdout=subprocess.PIPE as parameter, by default stdout is None.

Comment: i am getting the the traceback 
```ValueError: <class 'json.decoder.JSONDecodeError'>: "Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)```

Comment: @SidharthPanda That means that the process didn't write anything to stdout. You could check `result.returncode` before attempting the conversion. Also see if anything was written to stderr.

Comment: actyally @tdelaney i am trying to use top command and want to convert the output in json  here is the code which i tried: 
```sell_cmd = subprocess.run("top -n3", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)```
aand as you suggested to try ```result.returncode``` it returns me ```0```

Comment: @SidharthPanda - `top` is a different beast. Since stdout isn't a terminal, you'll want to add `-b` for batch mode. And skip the intermediate shell `subprocess.run(["top", "-n3", "-b"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`. If that doesn't work... make it a new question here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
    result = json.load(result.read())
```

Comment: `json.load` is for file objects and `result` doesn't have a `read`.